# how to add validation message inside input field like place holder in angular

Tags: angular, angular16

how to add validation message inside input field like place holder in angular?
i need to display the validation message inside the input box in angular 16, is there any way to do the same

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" class="form-`enter code here`control" placeholder="Enter name" required>
                <mat-error class="validation-message" *ngIf="signUpForm?.get('name')?.hasError('required') && (signUpForm?.get('name')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('name')?.touched)">Name is required</mat-error>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Organization<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="organization" formControlName="organization" class="form-control">
                <mat-error class="validation-message" *ngIf="signUpForm?.get('organization')?.hasError('required') && (signUpForm?.get('organization')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('organization')?.touched)">Organization is required</mat-error>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Role<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="role" formControlName="role" class="form-control">
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm?.get('role')?.hasError('required') && (signUpForm?.get('role')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('role')?.touched)">Role is required</mat-error>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" formControlName="phoneNumber" class="form-control">
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm?.get('phoneNumber')?.hasError('required') && (signUpForm?.get('phoneNumber')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('phoneNumber')?.touched)">Phone number is required</mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('phoneNumber')?.hasError('minlength') && (signUpForm?.get('phoneNumber')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('phoneNumber')?.touched)">Invalid mobile number</mat-error>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="email" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm?.get('email')?.hasError('required') && (signUpForm?.get('email')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('email')?.touched)">Email is required</mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('email')?.hasError('email') && (signUpForm?.get('email')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('email')?.touched)">Invalid email format</mat-error>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="password" id="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm?.get('password')?.hasError('required') && (signUpForm?.get('password')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('password')?.touched)">Password is required</mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password')?.hasError('minlength') && (signUpForm?.get('password')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('password')?.touched)">Password must be at least 8 characters
                    long</mat-error>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm Password<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="form-control" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm?.get('confirmPassword')?.hasError('required') && (signUpForm?.get('confirmPassword')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('confirmPassword')?.touched)">Password is required</mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('confirmPassword')?.hasError('minlength') && (signUpForm?.get('confirmPassword')?.dirty || signUpForm?.get('confirmPassword')?.touched)">Password must be at least 8 characters
                    long</mat-error>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="signUpForm.invalid" class="btn submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: You can bind the error message for the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the placeholder attribute of the input element:

```
   getPlaceholder(fieldName: string, defaultPlaceholder: string): string {
      const control = this.signUpForm.get(fieldName);
      if (control.hasError('required') && (control.dirty || 
         control.touched)) {
        return 'This field is required';
      } else if (control.hasError('minlength') && (control.dirty || 
        control.touched)) {
        return 'Minimum length required';
      } else if (control.hasError('email') && (control.dirty || 
        control.touched)) {
        return 'Invalid email format';
      }

      return defaultPlaceholder;
    }
```

And in the template:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
     <input 
       type="text" 
       id="name" 
       formControlName="name" 
       class="form-control" 
       [placeholder]="getPlaceholder('name', 'Enter name')">
 </div>
```

Implement this for the other form controls also.